# inline javascript get locale in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need current locale. I get locale code and send it to javascript. This code throw error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var loc = [[${#locale}]];
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: ru_RU is not defined.

What is the problem? This one not throw error:

```
<div th:text="${#locale}"></div>
```

Comment: You have to use `<script th:inline="javascript">` as the [script tag attribute](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining).

Comment: Thanks with this start work.

Answer (score 1):

Either add quotes so you have

`var loc = "[[${#locale}]]";`

or change `type="text/javascript"` to `th:inline="javascript"`

This is because `[[${#locale}]]` translated to `ru_RU` without quotes is considered as variable, not string, this is why you get ReferenceError